# Android EditText text is not vertically centered

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have search bar that defines EditBox like

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_editbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_execute_imageview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_back_logo"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_holo_light"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_states"
    android:padding="5dip"        
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/main_text_size" />
```

Despite `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` the text is not in the middle, but closer to upper side.

[image]

Comment: android:layout_centerVertical="true" will put edittext  in center not its text,for its text to center align use android:gravity="center"

Comment: You have to use android:gravity= "center" to align text to center

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
 android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is right but it is recommended to use:

`android:gravity="start|center_vertical"` instead of ("`left`") to avoid formatting errors.

Answer (score -1):

just change your gravity value to "left center align".

```
android:gravity:"left|center"
```

Comment: @Moes I didn't get you which answer  is not provided, can you please explain.

Comment: I thought any one can get by just property. I didn't find it require too much explanation though I have updated my answer kindly check it.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"
    android:textAlignment="center" >
</EditText>
```